# Is it possible to auto increment repeater control?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a repeater control on my web page that displays images as a result of a search.  The user searches for a keyword, and my program stores the search results in a data table.  The repeater then displays the images in the data table.  So, if there are 150 images in the data table, the repeater will display all 150 images.  Here's the code for my repeater:

```
<div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="background-color: Silver; border-style: solid; display: inline-block;
                float: left; margin: 5px; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblImage" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "image") %>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="requestLink" runat="server" Text="Original" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "requestUrl") %>'>
                    </asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

What if, however, I don't want to display all 150 images?  Is there a way to only display, say, 20 at a time and let the repeater auto expand when the user scrolls down or hits a 'MORE' button, or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to leverage the `PagedDataSource`, have a look at this link: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx

Comment: You need to use ajax with jquery or ajaxtoolkit components for that

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, that looks to be exactly what I need.  You should put it as an answer so that I can accept it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JavaRox, no worries, the content of the link (i.e. what you have to implement) is too broad to provide as an answer and when providing just links the community prefers they are just comments. I'm just glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, Well, I greatly appreciate your help.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to search for auto refresh or scroll event of mouse.

for auto refresh you can write this kind of code in javascript using that you can reload page after every interval

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(function () {
        load()
    }, 30000);

    var load = function () {
        location.reload();
    };  
</script>
```

and on Load event of page you have to rebind data to repeater.